# zooming two figures together in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a demonstration that needs to be distributed over two screens, each of which will have a stack of three time series plots. Within each figure, I use:

```
fig,(ax0,ax1) = plt.subplots(3,1,sharex=True)
```

Is there a way to coordinate across two figures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems by "coordinate across figures" you mean extending the sharing to the axes of the other figure.  This is possible.

As the axes of each of the figures are already shared with each other through the `subplots`' `sharex=True` it is sufficient to additionally share one of the axes in the first figure with one of the axes of the second figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1, axes1 = plt.subplots(3,1,sharex=True)
for ax in axes1:
    ax.plot([1,3,1])

fig2, axes2 = plt.subplots(3,1,sharex=True)
for ax in axes2:
    ax.plot([1,3,1])

## Share one of the axes in the first figure 
## with one of the axes of the second figure.
axes2[0].get_shared_x_axes().join(axes2[0],axes1[0])


plt.show()
```

Comment: Is this also possible if sharex cannot be True, for instance, if one subplot has floats and the second has dates for the x-axis? Because it that case sharex doesn't work but it would be nice to still zoom both subplots simultaneously.

Comment: @Johngoldenboy In the case you describe you would need a relationship between the units of both axes. If you have that, you can use a `xlim_changed` event and set the limits of the other axes.